# App not work in background - Ui.thread + Timer

Tags: android, kotlin

I create easy first my App in Android Studio but i dont know why my App not work in background.

The application works very well if it is on all the time, but when I hide it, it stops working. What am I doing wrong? I try used Intent for background ready but.. i think here is my problem :<

"MojaKlasa" is empty class. If I replace "MojaKlasa" with "MainActivity" in Intent, the application starts, but when the condition from Timer is met, it stops working and turns off.

My code:

```
package com.example.vicky.notificationexample

import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.app.Notification
import android.app.NotificationChannel
import android.app.NotificationManager
import android.app.PendingIntent
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory
import android.graphics.Color
import android.net.Uri
import android.os.Build
import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.VibrationEffect
import android.os.Vibrator
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.util.Log
import android.view.View
import android.widget.RemoteViews
import org.jetbrains.anko.doAsync
import org.jetbrains.anko.toast
import org.jetbrains.anko.uiThread
import java.net.URL
import java.nio.charset.Charset
import java.util.*
import java.util.concurrent.Executors

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var notificationManager : NotificationManager
    lateinit var notificationChannel : NotificationChannel
    lateinit var builder : Notification.Builder
    private val channelId = "com.example.vicky.notificationexample"
    private val description = "Test notification"

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        notificationManager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager

        val intent = Intent(this,MojaKlasa::class.java)
        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)

        val contentView = RemoteViews(packageName,R.layout.notification_layout)
        contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.tv_title,"Test")
        contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.tv_content,"Notify")

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            notificationChannel = NotificationChannel(channelId,description,NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH)
            notificationChannel.enableLights(true)
            notificationChannel.lightColor = Color.GREEN
            notificationChannel.enableVibration(false)
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel)

            builder = Notification.Builder(this,channelId)
                    .setContent(contentView)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_round)
                    .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.resources,R.drawable.ic_launcher))
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
        }else{

            builder = Notification.Builder(this)
                    .setContent(contentView)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_round)
                    .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.resources,R.drawable.ic_launcher))
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
        }

        val executor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(5)

        doAsync(executorService = executor){
            val result = URL("https://linkdomain/app2.php").readText()
            uiThread {
                toast(result)
                var stare:Int = result.toInt()

        Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(object : TimerTask() {

            @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat", "ServiceCast")
            override fun run() {

                val url = URL("https://linkdomain/app.php").readText(Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1"))
                url.toInt();

                if (url > stare.toString()) {
                    stare = stare.toInt()+1
                    val vibrator = getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE) as Vibrator
                    if (vibrator.hasVibrator()) { // Vibrator availability checking
                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                            vibrator.vibrate(VibrationEffect.createOneShot(500, VibrationEffect.DEFAULT_AMPLITUDE)) // New vibrate method for API Level 26 or higher
                        } else {
                            vibrator.vibrate(500) // Vibrate method for below API Level 26
                        }
                    }
                   notificationManager.notify(stare.toInt(),builder.build())
                }
                //Log.d("TAG", "url "+url)
                //Log.d("TAG", "cos "+stare)
            }
        }, 0, 1000) //put here time 1000 milliseconds=1 second
        }
        }


    }

    fun buTestUpdateText2 (view: View) {
        val destination = Intent(this@MainActivity.baseContext, MainActivity::class.java)
                .also { it.putExtra("KEY", 0) }
        startActivity(destination)
    }

}
```

Comment: You may need to reduce the amount of unnecessary code, so the people can focus on your problem easily.

Comment: In fact, I already slimmed it down as much as I could. I think all the code is needed to track the bug

Comment: Someone will help me?